# JPQL unexpected AST node: around "coalesce"

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

> JPQL got an error : threw
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException
>   (org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST
>   node: ( near line 3, column 48 ) select invoiceBE from InvoiceBE
>   invoiceBE where invoiceBE.institutionId = ?1 and
>   coalesce(invoiceBE.paidActivity.date < ?2) and
>   invoiceBE.exportedActivity.date < ?3 order by
>   invoiceBE.vendorInvoiceNumber asc

Is there any error around "coalesce"?

I run the sql well in mysql database.

```
select
        *    from
        ACQ_INVOICE invoice 
    where
        invoice.institution_id=91475
        and coalesce(invoice.`user_paid_date` < '2020-01-20', invoice.`paid_date` < '2020-01-20T16:45:40.786Z')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to

coalesce(invoice.`user_paid_date`, invoice.`paid_date`)< '2020-01-20'

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The coalesce expression looks all wrong.

I don't think back ticks to quote a property are allowed. That looks more like MySQL SQL syntax.

I'm also not completely sure if `COALESCE` may be used with boolean expressions.